# Any way to prevent emacs package manager from loading a single package on startup?

Tags: emacs, elisp, elpa

Basically, I share a single .emacs.d across several machines and have one package that I only want on my home machine (org-journal). I like using the package manager to keep this up to date, but it loads the package on every machine which causes some interference to a normal work flow.

Is there a way to get the package manager to skip loading this one package but load all others?

ETA: I tried only loading it on my desktop via

```
(when (string-equal (system-name) "will-desktop") 
     (require 'org-journal))
```

but that didn't work because using `(package-initialize)` early on in my **init.el** automatically loads it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `package-load-list` variable.

The default value is `(all)`, and the docstring says that `all` affects only packages not specified by other elements, so by my reading, you could simply add the following to inhibit `org-journal`:

```
(setq package-load-list '((org-journal nil) all))
```

If you're forcibly initialising the package manager in your init file, make sure you make this change beforehand.

*Edit:* Tested and updated/fixed. `add-to-list` was wrong, as the variable isn't already defined at that point.

Comment: Brilliant. I saw that variable, but didn't know there was a way to exclude one entry like that. I like that I learned something new about emacs lisp today.